# RankX within a subset of a group

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, rank

I am relatively new to PBI and I am trying to add a Rank measure that will Rank a product (within a product group) highest price to lowest:

```
Product Number  Net Price       Desired Result
Cat              $7.00              1
Cat              $6.00              2
Cat              $5.00              3
Cat              $4.00              4
Dog              $3.00              1
Dog              $1.00              2
```

The measure I've added comes up as an error: ​Rank Price by Product:  RANKX(ALL('Product Table'),[Net Price]).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
_maxOfRow =
MAX ( 'Product Table'[Net Price] )

_rank =
VAR _0 =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Product Table'[Product Number] ) )
VAR _1 =
    RANKX (
        FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( 'Product Table' ), 'Product Table'[Product Number] = _0 ),
        [_maxOfRow],
        ,
        DESC
    )
RETURN
    _1
```

[image: Solution]